# recursively querying multiple CSVs via node js

Tags: node.js, csv, file-io

I asked a question on [writing matched lines with node js in CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223303/writing-matched-lines-with-node-js-in-csv) and got a satisfactory answer. Now I am moving to the next level of my newbie adventures with node. I want to set up recursive queries that emulate a rdb, kinda (this is where I wish node had something like Perl's [DBD::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV).

*Update:* I think I am getting bit by the async-ness of things here in node world, and need to understand how that works. Here is what I am trying to do --

1. query the **foods** file for all matching foods.
2. for each matching food from #1 above, find all the nutrients from the **nutrients** file.
3. for each matched nutrient from #2 above, find their definitions in the **nutrient definitions** file.
4. return the entire data structure as a nested JSON and hand it to a visualizer (command line or html, when I eventually wrap this entire rat's nest into a RESTful framework such as `expressjs`.

Yes, I can do all this more trivially if I put everything into `SQLite`, but I am a sucker for pain. This would be a good way to understand how node deals with flow.

Here is my code so far

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var Argv = require("optimist").argv,
    Csv = require("csv"),
    Fs = require("fs");

var db = {
    "dir": "/../data/sr26",
    "foods": {
        "file": "FOOD_DES.txt",
        "columns": [
            "NDB_No", "FdGrp_Cd", "Long_Desc", "Shrt_Desc", "ComName",
            "ManufacName", "Survery", "Ref_desc", "Refuse", "SciName",
            "N_Factor", "Pro_Factor", "Fat_Factor", "CHO_Factor"
        ],
        "PK": "NDB_No",
        "search": "Long_Desc"
    },
    "nutrients": {
        "file": "NUT_DATA.txt",
        "columns": [
            "NDB_No", "Nutr_No", "Nutr_Val", "Num_Data_Pts", "Std_Error",
            "Src_Cd", "Deriv_Cd", "Ref_NDB_No", "Add_Nutr_Mark", 
            "Num_Studies", "Min", "Max", "DF", "Low_EB", "Up_EB", 
            "Stat_cmt", "AddMod_Date", "CC"
        ],
        "PK": "NDB_No",
        "search": "NDB_No"
    },
    "nutrient definitions": {
        "file": "NUTR_DEF.txt",
        "columns": [
            "Nutr_No", "Units", "Tagname", "NutrDesc", "Num_Dec", "SR_Order"
        ],
        "PK": "Nutr_No",
        "search": null
    },
    "query": function(table, value, done) {
        var re = new RegExp(value);

        Csv()
        .from.stream(
            Fs.createReadStream(__dirname + db.dir + "/" + db[table].file),
            {
                "delimiter": "^",
                "quote": "~",
                "columns": db[table].columns
            }
        )
        .transform(function(row, index, callback) {
            if (row[ db[table].search ].search(re) != -1) {
                process.nextTick(function() {
                     callback(null, row)
                });
            }
            else {
                callback(null, null);
            }
        })
        .on("record", function(row, index) {
            console.log("done is " + done);
            if (done == true) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            }
            else {
                console.log("found " + table + " '" + value + "' with PK: " + row[ db[table].PK ]);
                console.log("\tnow querying 'nutrients' for " + row[ db[table].PK ] + "\n");
                db.query("nutrients", row[ db[table].PK ], true);
            }
        });
    }
};

if (Argv.table) {
    console.time("searching");
    db.query(Argv.table, Argv.value, false);
    console.timeEnd("searching");
}

$ bin/app.js --table foods --value "Dandelion green"
searching: 4ms
done is false
found foods 'Dandelion green' with PK: 11207
    now querying 'nutrients' for 11207

done is false
found foods 'Dandelion green' with PK: 11208
    now querying 'nutrients' for 11208

done is false
found foods 'Dandelion green' with PK: 11782
    now querying 'nutrients' for 11782
```

As you can see, running the above spits out, well, really nothing. I was expecting the nutrient values to be printed out in the second loop "(done is true)" but "done" is never set to *true*. In my quest to learn node better, I seek both specific and general guidance on the above.